# how to upload different files (images & documents) in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

hi i'm new to codeigniter, can you please help me in insert multiple files(documents and images) in code igniter. here's my sample code

view:

```
<label>Picture</label>
            <input type="file" name="userfile" size="100" /> 

<label>Document</label>
           <input type="file" name="documentfile" size="10" />
```

controller:

```
 $m = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
 $n = $_FILES['documentfile']['name'];
  if ($m !== "")
        {
            $config['upload_path'] = './upload_images/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg|gif';
            $config['max_size'] = '0'; // 0 = no file size limit
            $config['max_width']  = '0';
            $config['max_height']  = '0';
            $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
             $this->upload->do_upload();
             $upload_result = $this->upload->data();
        }
       elseif ($n !== "")
        {
            $config_document['upload_path'] = './upload_documents/';
            $config_document['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';
            $config_document['max_size'] = '0';
            $config_document['overwrite'] = TRUE;
            $this->load->library('upload', $config_document);
             $this->upload->do_upload();
             $upload_result2 = $this->upload->data();
        }   
 $image_filename = $upload_result['file_name'];
 $docu_filename = $upload_result2['file_name '];
$this->MODEL->add_asset($image_filename, $docu_filename);
```

i tried to echo both file names and it works but my $docu_filename generates NULL value;
please help. thank you

Comment: can you post the complete html form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi its simple just check the file extension of uploaded file and make settings according to that. one more thing you have to set your html form enctype also. check the following example

**form View**

```
<form method="post" action="controller" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input type="file" name="test">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

in controller

```
 $path = $_FILES['test']['name'];
 $ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
 $img_ext_chk = array('jpg','png','gif','jpeg');
 $doc_ext_chk = array('pdf','doc');

if (in_array($ext,$img_ext_chk))
        {
            $config['upload_path'] = './upload_images/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg|gif';
            $config['max_size'] = '0'; // 0 = no file size limit
            $config['max_width']  = '0';
            $config['max_height']  = '0';
            $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
             $this->upload->do_upload();
             $upload_result = $this->upload->data();
        }
       elseif (in_array($ext,$doc_ext_chk))
        {
            $config_document['upload_path'] = './upload_documents/';
            $config_document['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';
            $config_document['max_size'] = '0';
            $config_document['overwrite'] = TRUE;
            $this->load->library('upload', $config_document);
             $this->upload->do_upload();
             $upload_result2 = $this->upload->data();
        }
```

Comment: you only put 1 <input type>, in my case i have 2 <input type>
i have two upload files, the <input type='file' name='userfile'> and <input type='file' name='documentfile'>
is it possible ? thank you.

Comment: you want to upload both file in one time or just one file in one time if one file in one time then use only one field if you have more then use 2 or more fields and check extension in same way

Comment: i want to upload both file in one time,
i just used $ext2 = pathinfo($path2, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
but i received null values.

Comment: Message: Undefined variable: upload_result2;
upload_result2 return null value and i cant save it to the database. please help.thank you

Comment: because else if is not executing and your upload_result2 is defined within that better to put both upload_result and upload_result2 outside conditions $upload_result = ''; upload_result =''; if condition true then get other value

Comment: my error now is that the original name getting is from the image.png, 
i use print_r($upload result) for image1.png and print_r($upload_result2) for docu.docx;
my error is that the array for docu.docx is that the  [orig_name] => image.png instead of docu.docx,